# Android: Adding notification to status bar

Tags: android, notifications

I have created a notification with **NotificationCompat.Builder** but i don't know how to show it in status bar. I tried using

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                               getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

but it doesn't work on 2.2 so i need another way...

this is my notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setContentTitle("Message")
            .setContentText("Notification");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it doesn't work on 2.2

Yes it does.

[This sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/DownloadNotify) shows an `IntentService` downloading a file and displaying a `Notification` using `NotificationCompat.Builder`. It uses code pretty much like yours for actually raising the `Notification`:

```
NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ID, b.build());
```

This code works fine on Android 2.2, as I just tried it (again) on an emulator, and the `Notification` displays as expected.

Comment: @Vladimir: I'd try `setTicker()` and `setWhen()`.